# How to make grid row Ready Only in magento 2 using UI component?

Tags: magento2, grid

In **magento 1** we were using **getRowurl()** method to make row read only(non-editable) but how we make grid row non-editable in **magento 2**?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is just comment below lines from **grid_listing.xml**

```
    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">

                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">

                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">channels_grid_listing.channels_grid_listing.channels_grid_columns.actions</item>

                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>

                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">

<!--                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>

                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>-->

                        </item>

                    </item>
```

Note: You can see commented line in snippet below.